# WinForms Datagridview - Lookup "Form"

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, lookup

I'm developing invoice app. Product table is linked with InvoiceLineItems table, so that user
can choose product from dropdown list of combobox where all available products are listed.
I want another solution for choosing product
Now I want to choose product from another form, whos shown when user enters product column.
That form has search capability for quick finding product by name or product code.
After choosing product, lookup column in datagridview should select that product in the list,
of course DisplayMember-ValueMember is set before for lookup column.
Is this possible and how to do it??? 
Code:

```
_products = this._productService.GetAllProducts();//returns List<ProductModel>
...
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn products = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
products.ValueMember = "ID";
products.DisplayMember = "Name";
dgvLineItems.Columns.Add(products);
products.DataSource = _products;
```

...
This code allow me to choose product from combobox in datagridview, product_id is saved in database for selected product and that works fine. BUT as I said before I want to search
and select for product in separate form and that this choice is reflected in combobox.
Reason for this is because I have 3000 products in database and many of them have similar name and sometimes it takes time to find product in the combobox...
Alternative solution is also welcome.

Comment: Sorry for the picture, I am new user so I don't have enough points to upload picture.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understended you right,you can try next solution:

In your "Lookup" form, create public method that will be able to return productId. This method will call the ShowDialog method of this form and in the end will return to your main form slected item. In the end, set selected value in the combobox:

Search form:

```
 int selectedProductId = -1;

    public int Display()
    {
        this.ShowDialog();

        return selectedProductId;
    }
```

Main Form:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
  int selectedProduct;
        if (e.ColumnIndex == productColumn)//Check that user entered relevant column
        {
            selectedProduct = searchForm.Display();
        }

//Set value
products.SelectedValue = selectedProduct;

    }
```